# Meaning of compact cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

I understand the meaning of singular  cohomology but not compact cohomology. Can anyone tell me what it means? We know the former "detects" holes. What does the latter detect?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "compact cohomology". Do you mean cohomology with compact support? Try to work out some examples, like $H^*c(R^n)$, $H^*_c(S^n\times R)$, or/and $H^*_c$ of the plane minus $k$ points. You will gain plenty of insight by doing these exercises.